# How to expand Ng2-tree Node programmatically?

Tags: angular, typescript, treeview

i am using [**ng2-tree**](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree)  to display Tree in my application. My requirement is when a user clicks on any tree node , if the tree has any children then it should be expanded else it will make API call to bring child of that node.

My problem is i am not able to find any method to expand the node. Here is the method i have written which is called when user clicks on any node :

```
handleSelectedNode(e: NodeEvent): void {
    let child;
    let node;
    if (e.node.hasChildren()) {

         // method to expand child 
    }
    else { // make api call to get child}
```

Is there any way to achieve that ??  I could only find a method called node.isexpanded(); which returns if the node is expanded or not . How can i set it to true or false ??

Comment: I think you can raise a query in there git repo itself, don see any documentation for it. is this the package you are using https://github.com/martinsik/ng2-treeview ?

Comment: @gusaindpk i have used ng2-tree to implement the tree. link : https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree  .